# Can not pull right data using Azure Aduit Logs using Graph API thru Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to pull out [Azure Audit logs using Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I am using Powershell to do this nut I can't get filtering to work.

For example, this URL returns lots of older data than then date specified in the filter.
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?\$filter=activityDateTime ge 2020-02-24T18:39:36Z`

Here is my code

```
$ClientID = "yyyyyy" 
$ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx" 
$loginURL       = "https://login.microsoftonline.com" 
$tenantdomain   = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$resource       = "https://graph.microsoft.com" 

$Date = Get-Date
$UTC = $Date.ToUniversalTime();
$UTC
$Time = "{0:s}" -f $UTC.AddMinutes(-5) + "Z"
$Time

$body       = 
@{grant_type="client_credentials";resource=$resource;client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
$oauth      = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$tenantdomain/oauth2/token?api- 
version=1.0 -Body $body
$headerParams = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?\`$filter=activityDateTime ge ' + 
$Time

$Data = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Uri $url
$DataFromJson = $Data.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$ValueFromJason = $DataFromJson.value
$AllAuditData += $ValueFromJason

# Output
$Time
2020-02-24T18:39:36Z

$short = $AllAuditData | Sort-Object activityDateTime
$short[1].activityDateTime
2020-02-24T17:52:09.9673372Z  # Old data as comparison to $Time
$short[-1].activityDateTime
2020-02-24T18:44:15.1283452Z
```

Comment: It should be `?$filter` not `?\`$filter`

Comment: Already tried that ;-) no luck.

Comment: If you have outer single quotes, you don't need to escape anything other than inside single quotes. So no need to escape the `$`. You may need to surround the date/time with single quotes. You could try `'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?\$filter=activityDateTime ge ''2020-02-24T18:39:36Z'''`. Maybe it hates the `Z`. I don't have a way of testing this right now.

Comment: I think it works, was reading wrong. I was trying activitydisplayname. This one works in explorer but can't make it work in powershell https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=startswith(activityDisplayName, 'Export')

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use the following script

```
$ClientID = "yyyyyy" 
$ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx" 
$loginURL       = "https://login.microsoftonline.com" 
$tenantdomain   = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$resource       = "https://graph.microsoft.com" 
$body       = 
@{grant_type="client_credentials";resource=$resource;client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
$oauth      = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$tenantdomain/oauth2/token?api- 
version=1.0 -Body $body

$Date = Get-Date
$UTC = $Date.ToUniversalTime();
$Time = "{0:s}" -f $UTC.AddMinutes(-5) + "Z"
$Time


$url= "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?`$filter=activityDateTime gt " + $Time
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)")
$AllAuditData=@()
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers 
$AllAuditData += $response.value


$short = $AllAuditData | Sort-Object activityDateTime
$short[1].activityDateTime

$short[-1].activityDateTime
```

[image]

---

## Update

According to my research, we can use the Azure AD PowerShell command `Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs` to filter audit logs. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-powershell-reporting.

For example

```
Install-module AzureADPreview

Connect-AzureAD 
$result=Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Update user'"
$result | Select-Object ActivityDisplayName
```

[image]

Comment: Yep. This one works without that ` before $filter. Can you try filter on activityDisplayName (like "Update User") and see if you can find the right construct for the URL.  I am having a hard time with that.

Comment: @Pandap Do you have any other concerns? if you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?